# How can I change following crypto code to use crypto-js

Tags: encryption, cryptojs, vite

I wanted to use ViteJs. For the purpose, I need to use [CryptoJS](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/) instead of Crypto. Current code using crypto is working fine.

```js
const crypto = require('crypto');
export function encrypt(plainText, secret) {
    const iv = crypto.randomBytes(16);
    const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', secret, iv);
    let cipherText;
    try {
        cipherText = cipher.update(plainText, 'utf8', 'hex');
        cipherText += cipher.final('hex');
        cipherText = iv.toString('hex') + cipherText
    } catch (e) {
        cipherText = null;
    }
    return cipherText;
}

export function decrypt(cipherText, secret) {
    const contents = Buffer.from(cipherText, 'hex');
    const iv = contents.slice(0, 16);
    const textBytes = contents.slice(16);
    const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc', secret, iv);
    let decrypted = decipher.update(textBytes, 'hex', 'utf8');
    decrypted += decipher.final('utf8');
    return decrypted;
}
```

Here I want to encrypt on JS and decrypt on Golang. Please help converting the following code to use CryptoJS

The CryptoJS code I tried but didn't work on golang

```js
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js'

export const encrypt = (plainText: string, secret: string) => {
  const iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(16)
  const encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(plainText, secret, {
    iv,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
  })
  return iv + encrypted.toString()
}

export const decrypt = (cipherText: string, secret: string) => {
  const iv = cipherText.slice(0, 32)
  const ivEx = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(iv)
  cipherText = cipherText.replace(iv, '')
  const decrypt = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(cipherText, secret, {
    ivEx,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
  })
  return decrypt.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)
}
```

Golang code I used to decrypt

```golang
// Decrypt decrypts cipher text string into plain text string
func Decrypt(encrypted string, password string) (string, error) {
    key := []byte(password)
    cipherText, err := hex.DecodeString(encrypted)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%v", err)
        return "", err
    }
    block, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%v", err)
        return "", err
    }

    if len(cipherText) < aes.BlockSize {
        return "", errors.New("cipherText too short")
    }
    iv := cipherText[:aes.BlockSize]
    cipherText = cipherText[aes.BlockSize:]
    if len(cipherText)%aes.BlockSize != 0 {
        return "", errors.New("cipherText is not a multiple of the block size")
    }

    mode := cipher.NewCBCDecrypter(block, iv)
    mode.CryptBlocks(cipherText, cipherText)

    cipherText, _ = pkcs7.Unpad(cipherText, aes.BlockSize)
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s", cipherText), nil
}
```

Comment: What does your recent CryptoJS code look like?

Comment: @Topaco I've updated the original question with the Code. The Encryption/Decryption works well within JS but the encrypted code can't be decrypted on golang

Comment: It's not clear from your post how you pass the key in the CryptoJS code. It must be passed as `WordArray`, otherwise it will be interpreted as passphrase. For the conversion to a `WordArray` an [encoder](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#encoders) can be used, e.g. the `Hex` encoder as for the IV in the `decrypt()` method.

Comment: Also, the `encrypt()` method must return `iv + encrypted.ciphertext.toString()`, otherwise the 2nd part will be Base64 encoded (since `toString()` is overloaded in this way).

Comment: @Topaco Key is passed as string

Comment: As suspected. This is wrong. You have to pass it as a `WordArray`. Also note that there are multiple issues in the CryptoJS `decrypt()` method, but since you decrypt with Go you don't need that method, so I' ll skip the details.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Changing it to WordArray fixed the issue. I would also appreciate if you could explain the issues with `decrypt()`

Comment: In the CryptoJS `decrypt()` method, the ciphertext must be parsed analogously to the IV with the Hex encoder (also, `cipherText.slice(32)` seems more robust to me than `cipherText.replace(iv, '')`). In the `CryptoJS.AES.decrypt()` call, the ciphertext must be passed as `CipherParams` object, i.e. `{ciphertext: cipherText}`, and the IV as `iv: ivEx`.

Comment: Will try to fix decrypt as well. Thanks again for your help :)